# socket.io router, assign to one of multiple instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, forwarding

I am trying to overcome a limitation placed on how many connections `TCP` protocol can have opened on a single port. So i thought of a way to create multiple instances of my server running on different ports for example:

- instance 1 (3001) `server_i1.js`
- instance 2 (3002) `server_i2.js`
- instance 3 (3003) `server_i3.js`
- instance 4 (3004) `server_i4.js`

then i could have one additional file `server_route.js` that would check how many connections are established on each instance and forward user to less populated instance. I tried build something using cluster but it only seems to create new processes on the same port. How it can be done to have all users connect for example to `http://exmaple.com:3000` and then forward them to one of four possible ports `[3001, 3002, 3003, 3004]`?

current server approach:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if(cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
    });
} else {

    var http = require('http'),
        _io = require('socket.io'),
        server = http.createServer();

    server.listen('3000', 'example.com');

    var io = _io.listen(server);

    var connections = {},
        msg_sent = 0;

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {

        connections[socket.id] = new Date().getTime();

        socket.on('client-request', function(msg) {
            msg_sent++;
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            delete connections[socket.id];
        });

    });

    setInterval(function() {
        console.log( 'Active connections: ', Object.keys(connections).length, 'Messages sent: ', msg_sent );
    }, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use round robin? A sample implementation would look like this:

```
 const ports = ["3001"," 3002", "3003"];
 var current = 0;

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit("redirect",ports[current]);
  current = (current + 1) % ports.length;
});
```

On clientside one would do

```
(function start(port){
  const socket = io("http://localhost:"+port);
  socket.on("redirect", port => (socket.close(), start(port)));
  //whatever
})(3000);
```

Comment: this is really nice thought, the only problem would be with how to balance load between servers, do you have any thoughts on how to ?

Comment: @mevia thats the thing of round robin. If there are a lot of connections, the workload will be distributed equally between servers...